# Camunda Cockpit doesn't start

Tags: java, maven, wildfly, camunda

I am using Windows 10, jdk 1.8.0, Eclipse Neon 3.0, wildfly 10 downloaded from camunda website, which includes Camunda BPM as part of WildFly 10.

My porblem: Camunda cockpit doesn't start in browser and gives 404 error! I'd like to know how to start make it appear. I was using Tomcat server and it worked,  but now that I am using wildfly the cockpit doesn't start.

What I have done is as follows:

I have designed a BPMN model. Then by following the instruction in the following link:

https://docs.camunda.org/get-started/javaee6/

I have saved my BPMN model in src>main>resources, made the java classes in a maven project, add dependencies to pom.xml. Successfully built the project. Right click on the pom.xml, run as maven clean, run as maven isntall. After .war file is created in target folder copy it in camunda-bpm-wildfly10-7.7.0 > server > wildfly-10.1.0.Final > standalone > deployments, run start-camunda.bat. At this moment a page in browser opens with "404 - Not Found" error.

The cannot send the error I am getting at cmd.exe-standalone.bat because stackoverflow detects links in it and I can't use more than 2 links, but I can see my deployed file (myFile.war.deployed) in deployments!

I appreciate appreciate your help.
.5 (Final)

Comment: Check the Wildfly log files if they contain any errors or other relevant messages.

Comment: It is built successfully. So there is no error in the log file. The problem is not deploying. It is deployed but the cockpit is not opening.

Comment: Please paste the log of your Wildfly here. What url are you opening in the browser.